# Setting keyboard type for html textarea

Tags: html, angular

I am running a angular2 app on a mobile device. I have a textarea and once focused the mobile device shows the keyboard. I would like to set the keyboard to the twitter keyboard type. Is this possible using html5 or in another way?

Comment: What the heck is a "twitter keyboard?"

Comment: It´s a keyboard which is specific for Twitter use
http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/twitter-specific-keyboard-uikeyboardtypetwitter.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You CAN NOT control which keyboard the client uses. At least not with pure html5/css/javascript. This depends on the system.

You can only use these properties to control (indirectly) how the keyboard appears:

- [HTML  type Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_type.asp)
- [HTML  pattern Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_pattern.asp)